# Linker can't find library when using CMake

Tags: c++, macos, cmake, makefile, linker-errors

I am trying to learn CMake using a youtube [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DDHCEE_PHOU&list=PLalVdRk2RC6o5GHu618ARWh0VO0bFlif4&index=2)

Installing the library with `make install` succeeded
(both `/usr/local/libmearlymath.a` and `/usr/local/include/adder.h` exist)

But when running `make` in the build folder for the executable I get this error:

```
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/testsome.dir/main.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable testsome
ld: library not found for -lmearlymath
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [testsome] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/testsome.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

### Project structure

```
├── SomeLibDemo
│   └── AddLibDemo
│       ├── CMakeLists.txt
│       ├── adder.cpp
│       ├── adder.h
│       └── build
│        
└── TestSome
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
    ├── build
    └── main.cpp
```

### In the library the files look accordingly:

**CMakeLists.txt:**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.27.2)
project(mearlymath)
add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} adder.cpp)
set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES PUBLIC_HEADER adder.h)
install(TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME} LIBRARY DESTINATION lib
    PUBLIC_HEADER DESTINATION include)
```

### In the executable the files look accordingly:

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.27.2)
project(testsome)
add_executable(testsome main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(testsome mearlymath)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the linker can't find the library, you have to make sure you actually included it correctly. For one, add this line (put it before `target_link_libraries`) to CMakeLists.txt:

`link_directories(/usr/local/lib)`

You can also be explicit and add a full path to the file and see if that works. For example:

`target_link_libraries(testsome /usr/local/lib/mearlymath.a)`